# VBA, Renaming the relevant sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, worksheet

I am using twice the command "Workbooks.Open Filename..." in order to open the file (which were already open the first time) from which to be copied from.

Is there an other economical solution without mentioning it twice but instead refering to the already open workbook? Furtheremore, the command:   ActiveSheet.Name = "Spread" doesnt rename in the pasted sheet. It does so only when I bring that relevant Sheets in front.

```
 Sub CopyAndPaste()

 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set wb = Workbooks.Add
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

 datDatum = Now


 Workbooks.Open        
 Filename:="C:\Users\........xls" *'the source file'*

 Sheets("Hypothekenbanken").Range("A11:P57").Copy
 ws.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
 ActiveSheet.Name = "Spread"
```

Comment: you cannot copy both. you have to copy -> insert -> copy -> insert. set different workbooks to do this w/o activeworkbook and select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about first copied values being overwritten by the second.
So you have to first copy first value -> paste first value -> copy second value -> paste second value

Something like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws as worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Sheets("Hypothekenbanken").Range("A11:P57").Copy
ws.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
Sheets("Landesbanken").Range("A11:P41").Copy
ws.Range("A3").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Hey @Yavuz Topal, it's not cool to edit your question to something completely different. My answer looks irrelevant now and it got unaccepted. You should post new question and keep the old one.

Comment: hi Kirszu, I am really sorry about this. I will keep it in mind for the next time. It won't happen again.

Comment: No problem! It is just a good habit to keep StackOveflow clear :)